# Omnisocial depends on gem bcrypt-ruby 2.1, but Rails 3.1 depends on bcrypt 3.0.0 - what do I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

Trying to test out this awesome looking gem - http://icelab.com.au/articles/welcome-to-the-omnisocial/ - that promises easy integration of Twitter & FB login to my app.

But, when I run `bundle install` I see this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bcrypt-ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    omnisocial depends on
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1)

    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
```

When I specify that I want `Bundler` to use version 2.1, I get this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bcrypt-ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1)

    rails (= 3.1.0) depends on
      bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
```

So now I have to choose between either Omnisocial or Rails 3.1. Seems like such a crappy choice.

What do I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've pushed released a new version of the gem (which I've had to rename to `omnipopulus` for legal reasons). This new release doesn't depend on any particular version of the `bcrypt-ruby` gem, so you should be fine to run it with Rails 3.1.

Add this to your `Gemfile` to get going:

```
gem 'omnipopulus'
```

Then run `bundle` and follow the instructions in the README at https://github.com/icelab/omnipopulus

Make sure that you've removed any references to omnisocial in your app.

Comment: Great. It installed perfectly. Thanks. Will let you know if I have any more issues.

Answer (score 0):

The current github version of omnisocial requires no particular version of bcrypt. [See here](https://github.com/icelab/omnisocial/blob/master/Gemfile#L7).

But they added a dependency to a RC version of Rails...

What I often do in these cases:

- clone the github repository
- change what I need
- run the gem's test suite
- if ok, add my own version to the Rails app
- if a new version of the gem is released an fit my needs, I use the official version again